# Erlang. Make relative path absolute

Tags: erlang, relative-path

I have a relative url and an absolute path and i want to resolve it to an absolute path.

Have tried using filename:abspath("test", "/root/").
and it works but not with relative paths like "../"
for example filename:abspath("../", "/root/").
gives "/root/../"

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at [mochiweb sources](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/b7f3693a9008de6d31a67174f7184fe24093a1b4/src/mochiweb_util.erl#L72) it could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation of filename:absname/1 says: "No attempt is made to create the shortest absolute name, because this can give incorrect results on file systems which allow links."

If your example filename:abspath("../", "/root/") would give you "/" (an "optimized" path) instead of "/root/../", it could actually refer to the wrong directory if "/root" is a link to some other directory like "/foo/bar/baz". Are you sure that an optimized path is what you want? The result from abspath/2 is correct, but perhaps not "pretty".